# uninitialized constant Base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Key < ActiveRecord::Base

  class << self

    def generate (key)
      Base64.encode64(key)
    end
  end
end
```

When calling `Key.generate` from a controller it works as expected. However, when calling `Key.generate` from a Rake::Task library I receive the error message:

> uninitialized constant Base64

Answer (score 20, accepted):

did you put `require 'base64'` inside `application.rb` after `require 'rails/all'`?

Comment: Probably best putting it in the Key class if that is only place its used

Comment: Yes, it's better to put it in the `Key` class file declaration.